# Hyper-V 2012 with Server 2003 Guest that requires IPX

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2012

Fairly stumped on this one.

I've got a `Hyper-V 2008R2` server hosting several server VMs.
We're looking to migrate to newer hardware and we want to run `Hyper-V 2012`.

I've picked up a Proliant ML350 G6, multiple processors, lots of RAM, RAID10.
Installed `HV Server 2012`, setup a couple windows servers on it everything runs great.

Until I try to migrate a `Windows 2003` server over from the `2008R2` box. This VM needs to communicate with a `Netware 6.5` server via `IPX`.
(I know. `Netware 6.5`? I'd get them to dump it if I could, but its a long story.) Anyway, for some reason this server moves over just fine, can login to AD, get access to everything with the exception of the `IPX` resources.

I'm currently just trying to use the CSNW included with 2003, thats been working fine for years on the `2008R2` server, I'd like to avoid adding in the Novell client if possible.

I've tried removing and reloading the integration components, reloading SP2, doing a repair install of 2003 and so many other things I can't even remember.

**TL;DR:** How can I get a VM running on `Hyper-V Server 2012` to communicate via `IPX` to other network resources?

**EDIT:**

My new Hyper-V host is running `Hyper-V Server 2012`. The guest in question is running `Windows Server 2003 R2`.

This guest has been running on a `Hyper-V Server 2008R2` platform for several years and communicating with a Physical Netware 6.5 server exclusively running `IPX`.

After moving the guest to the new host `IPX` communication has been unable to function. the `IPX` protocol loads fine, no errors, but when we try to login to the `Netware` box we get "The network path was not found."

Comment: Ok, so what is the question? I mean, i read it twice, and I do not find a single question in there that needs answer. I also fail to see how the network protocol of a virtual machine has anything to do with the host OS, given that the network of a VM is a virtualized network card.

Comment: Sorry, my problem is that the 2003 Guest needs to communicate with a server running IPX and it can't. As for why the host OS is relevant it seems pretty clear to me that the only change I made was the host OS and everything stopped working. So I'm pretty sure that the problem lies there.

Comment: Why not add TCPIP on the Novell server?

Comment: @GregAskew I think we've tried using IP on that system in the past and ran into trouble with a specific application running on it that was written with only ipx support.

Comment: Are the guest and the NetWare server in the same broadcast domain? Have you tried an ipx ping?

Comment: @longneck yes to both.

Comment: Why does the host need to talk to the client? I mean, the host should run hyper-v ONLY (plus admin, maybe file server, backup etc., but definitely no real payload)

Comment: The host doesn't need to talk to the guest at all. Let me try and clarify it with an edit.

Comment: @TomTom Hope that helps clarify things.

Comment: I am not sure i get it - the virtual network in Hyper-V should be ethernet and not care even about IP, or? I mean, i am not totally sure- i just do not run anything else. But it is a emulated ETHERNET card, not IP.

Comment: Install wireshark, see if the guest is actually transmitting anything. Then plug the upstream cable or mirror the switchport and see if you can spot the traffic there as well.

Comment: Is the network adapter in the vm synthetic or legacy?

Comment: +1 to both TomTom and SpacemanSpiff - You absolutely need to sniff the traffic in the guest and external to the host. The host shouldn't care one bit about the traffic being IPX-- as TomTom says it's a virtualized Ethernet NIC, not an IP interface. You're dropping bits on the floor somewhere and you just need to find out where. >smile<

Comment: Sorry guys, been busy. I'm going to move this into my lab this weekend and I'll update then.

Comment: @Nate I've tried both legacy and synthetic.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I am facing the same problem and I don't want to have to go back to 2008 R2

Comment: @Rick Nope, just went back to 2008r2 and dumped 2012 for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is going to be enabling IP on the NW server, to echo Greg. Otherwise, you're going to have to find some way to get the 2012 host machine to be able to speak/bridge/NAT/or otherwise route IPX, and I think that's a non-starter. You can dick around with the guest all you want, but unless the host can pass the protocol through (and you haven't explained how you're doing the networking), you're not going to get anywhere. I don't even feel like looking up the status of IPX under 2012.

/Edit - looks like I'm possibly incorrect in assuming that the HV host needs to speak IPX, assuming you're bridging the network in both scenarios. Hint - when I said "you haven't explained how you're doing the networking", that's the passive-aggressive way of saying "please explain how you're doing the networking". Both on the host side, and for the guests. There could be a lot of reasons your IPX isn't working; without details, I can only guess. By "External network", is that a bridged connection?

Comment: The network is literally the stock config that comes out of the install. 0 customization on this. Its a standalone host running some legacy systems they need to keep around for legal reasons for a few more years.  I've just clicked external network, and associated it with one of the ports on the nic. As for enabling IP, the reason we're using IPX is a custom written app that only wants to communicate over IPX.

Answer (score -1):

First of all i am sorry for my language. hope this is some help.

Win 2003 r2
Enable TC/ip on that sever so it can communicate whit network
Install FPNW (File and network for Netware Microsoft produkt) Then you have IPX
FPNW is downloadable from Microsoft site and you are license to 1000 concurrent connections

Disable remote desktop (not compatible whit FPNW) use Another software

Now its the tricky thing, Firewall..

If you disable firewall on guest and host system its going to work. But this is dangerus thing to do. So you have to manually open and config guest and host firewall settings..

Hope this is som clue

And sorry for my bad language!!